# iOS React Native app fails to install with Xcode 12 build tools when installed via Detox

Tags: react-native, xcodebuild, detox

I'm trying to run detox tests, on Android they run correctly.

When using Xcode 11 build tools, the app installs correctly and all tests run.

When using Xcode 12 the app fails to install. The app attempts to be installed 3 times, and eventually the simulator complains that it's unable to install and the app icon is darkened on the simulator.

I've tried debug and release configurations, and I am cleaning/building each time. Running the scheme directly in Xcode on v12, the application installs and works normally.

The build command:

```
xcodebuild -workspace ios/myapp.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme myscheme -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build/datapath
```

What am I missing to get this working on Xcode 12?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge, few previous versions of detox don't support Xcode 12. Upgrading detox might solve the issue.

Comment: While I have upgraded, the latest release (18.13) includes some additional debugging information that allowed me to determine that the initilization code needed to include an explicit call to "device.launchApp({args})". Awarding you the bounty based on partial answer. @artal also answered something similar, but yours was the first response.

Comment: Thankyou. It means a lot

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell why this happens. Personally I didn't run into such issues with Xcode 12.

You can try the following:

1. Make sure to use the latest Detox version, sometimes specific Xcode versions require some adjustments (there's Xcode 12.4, 12.5, etc.)
2. Make sure your `applesimutils` is up to date (see instructions [here](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Introduction.iOSDevEnv.md#install-applesimutils)).
3. RN apps sometimes have issues with the new build system, try adding `-UseModernBuildSystem=NO` to your `xcodebuild` command.

Comment: While I have upgraded, the latest release (18.13) includes some additional debugging information that allowed me to determine that the initilization code needed to include an explicit call to "device.launchApp({args})".